# Laravel 5 Access Denied to mysql in browser but not in tinker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, homestead

I've looked through a bunch of other threads but can't find a solution.  My .env file is set up correctly and I can access the database fine through the php artisan tinker command.  However when I spin it up on the browser I get access denied.  I've changed the password a few different times to make sure I was putting in the correct username/password but still nothing.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=rUzE03agyabewGSbhch7QFKE0jqZqifO5

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I have reloaded the virtualbox and even forced provisioned it, ran php config:clear, stop and started the mysql db. tried different users/passwords/dbs, switched localhost to 127.0.0.1, followed the documentation on laravel.com.  Nothing has worked.

I'm at a loss...help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this one? http://tutsnare.com/access-denied-for-user-homesteadlocalhost-laravel-5/

Comment: that's happened to me & i changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 & it worked, but i wasn't using virtual machine, so check your VB's ip , & if it's other than 127.0.0.1 try using that.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials were not very clear on this point but basically I had to access mysql on the VM by using "vagrant ssh" and then logging onto mysql through the cli to create the correct user.  Also all the migrate commands needed to be executed while logged into the VM through the ssh.

While the artisan commands will add the appropriate "make:' objects in either only the VM cli will allow you to access the correct database.  Hopefully this post will save someone a day of sifting through a lot of posts about the .env file.